# get length of string in UTF8

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get the length (not number of bytes) of a string in its UTF-8 encoded form (PHP's `mb_strlen(.., 'UTF-8')` equivalent)?

I tried `string.characters.count` but it does not return the correct length for certain characters like an emoji.

Example:

```
let s = "✌️"
print(s.characters.count) // prints 2, but should print 3.
```

Comment: Can you give some input/output combinations, like "abc" -> 3, "someUtf-8String" -> 123 to verify our solutions against!?

Comment: You can get UTF-8 count using string.utf8.count. You can get the array of UTF-8 code units themselves using: Array( string.utf8 ).

Comment: @luk2302 added an example.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30 about characters vs Unicode scalars vs UTF-16 vs UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the UTF-8 encoding of a string with the `.utf8` property. Use `count` on that to get the number of UTF-8 code units in the string:

```
let string = "\u{1f603}" // One of the smiley face emojis...

print(string.utf8.count) // prints "4"
```

Based on your edited question, what you are probably looking for is the number of `UnicodeScalar`s used to encode the string. You access that with the `unicodeScalars` property:

```
let s = "✌️"
print(s.unicodeScalars.count) // prints 3
```

The reason everyone is confused is because your original question asks for the length of the string in its UTF-8 encoded form. The answer that you actually wanted had nothing to do with the length of the string in its UTF-8 encoded form.

I think you are confused about the difference between Unicode "extended grapheme clusters", Unicode code points, and the various encodings (like UTF-8) that can be used to encode a Unicode code point.

A `Character` in Swift represents what Unicode calls an "extended grapheme cluster". That is to say, it is a single visual character, even if it is made up of multiple Unicode code points.

A Unicode code point is a single linguistic symbol that is given a 32-bit value. Two or more Unicode code points can combine to create a single `Character`. In Swift, the Unicode code point is represented by the `UnicodeScalar` type.

When it comes time to store a string, or send it over the internet, or otherwise turn it into data that is represented by bytes, you have to decide how to encode it. There are all kinds of encodings, the most common is probably UTF-8, which encodes the string as a series of `UInt8` values.

That's just a brief snippet of the difference between the three concepts. It is actually a really interesting subject and if you Google some of those terms, you will find a lot more good information.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. I've edited with an example.

Comment: You asked how to get the length of a string in its UTF-8 encoded form. That is the same as the number of bytes used to encode it. If that isn't what you are asking, then please edit your question.

Comment: It isn't related to UTF-8? I'm confused. I'm actually looking for the PHP's mb_strlen(.., 'UTF-8') equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

```
let str = "ačŘ"
print("str has \(str.characters.count) characters") // 3
print("and \(str.utf8.count) bytes as encoded in UTF-8") // 5
```

update (based on your notes)

```
let s = "✌️"

let arr:[UInt8] = [226, 156, 140, 240, 159, 143, 191, 239, 184, 143]
var arrCchar = arr.map { (uint8) -> Int8 in
    Int8(bitPattern: uint8)
}
arrCchar += [0] // to be null terminated

let str = String.fromCString(&arrCchar)
print(str) // Optional("✌️")
s == str // TRUE !!!!
```

by characters

```
s.characters.forEach { (c) -> () in
    let str = String(c)
    print(str.utf8.map{$0}, "which represents character: ", c)
    str.unicodeScalars.forEach({ (u) -> () in
        print("composed from unicode scalar(s): ", u.debugDescription)
    })
}
/*
[226, 156, 140] which represents character:  ✌
composed from unicode scalar(s):  "\u{270C}"
[240, 159, 143, 191, 239, 184, 143] which represents character:  ️
composed from unicode scalar(s):  "\u{0001F3FF}"
composed from unicode scalar(s):  "\u{FE0F}"
*/
```

Every character in Unicode can be represented by one or more unicode scalars. A unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number (and name) for a character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LOWERCASE LATIN LETTER A("a"), or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("\U0001f425").
        When a Unicode string is written to a text file or some other storage, these unicode scalars are encoded in one of several Unicode-defined formats. Each format encodes the string in small chunks known as code units. These include the UTF-8 format (which encodes a string as 8-bit code units) and the UTF-16 format (which encodes a string as 16-bit code units).

//copy from Apple Developer swift programming guide

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. I've edited with an example.

Comment: let s = "✌️"; print(s.characters.count) // 2   ??? at least on my computer. try s.characters.forEach{ print($0) }. by the way your s has 10 bytes, if encoded in UTF-8

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. I know it is 10 bytes. `.characters.count` prints 2 but the value that I want is 3.

Comment: why do you want 3, if there is 2 characters ? :-)

Comment: I want the PHP's `mb_strlen(s, 'UTF-8')` equivalent. You can try it here https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: see Roman's answer!!! s.unicodeScalars.count And check docs about the difference between character, unicode scalar and byte :-)